# rewrite OWL class expression as SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, owl

I have been familiarizing myself with AKSW's https://github.com/SmartDataAnalytics/OWL2SPARQL, which is pretty easy to use, even with Scala and sbt, but doesn't rewrite Class Expressions.

I ([and at least one other person](https://github.com/SmartDataAnalytics/OWL2SPARQL/issues/3)!) would find class expression -> SPARQL rewriting helpful.  Maybe that's because I (at least) make punning statements?  For example, I need to find all drug prescription individuals that mention any drug tablet **class** that (indirectly) has the chemical 'rosuvastatin' as an active ingredient

```
:X a 'drug prescription' .
:X mentions 'rosuvastatin Oral Tablet' .
```

where

- 'drug prescription' is http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PDRO_0000024
- mentions is http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000142
- 'rosuvastatin Oral Tablet' is http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00027869

*Superclasses & Asserted Axioms for 'rosuvastatin Oral Tablet':*

```
drug tablet
  has_proper_part some (scattered molecular aggregate and 
    (is bearer of some active ingredient) and 
        (has granular part some rosuvastatin))
```

where rosuvastatin is http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00018679 (and the other IRIs can be seen in RDF/XML context at http://www.ontobee.org/ontology/rdf/DRON?iri=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00027869)

**Are there other tools that can rewrite an OWL Class Expression as a SPARQL query?**

If not, I guess I might write a property chain shortcut... but that disregards the types of classes involved in the chain, right?

I have an example at https://github.com/turbomam/owl2sparql4turbo

Comment: What means *"doesn't rewrite Class Expressions."* - that's exactly one of the features of OWL2SPARQL, or not? Ok, basically it's converting OWL class expressions to SPARQL - but I'm wondering, what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: See this issue:  https://github.com/SmartDataAnalytics/OWL2SPARQL/issues/3 **plus** all of the examples at https://github.com/SmartDataAnalytics/OWL2SPARQL are assertions about individuals, not classes.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks.  I found my sloppy but relevant code and added links to the post

Comment: Thank you. I'll check the code/example tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

AKSW added the functionality I requested and gave me some good tips about using the OWL API.  My bridge from a Java stream to a Scala stream may be a little kludgy.

Clone https://github.com/turbomam/owl2sparql4turbo to see how I set up build.sbt to import dependencies.

Ontology **rots.owl** includes the axioms like these (in Manchester notation... RDF/XML or Turtle would be OK, too):

```
Class: obo:DRON_00027869

    Annotations: 
        rdfs:label "rosuvastatin Oral Tablet"^^xsd:string,
        obo:DRON_00010000 "402354"^^xsd:string

    SubClassOf: 
        obo:DRON_00000022,
        <http://www.obofoundry.org/ro/ro.owl#has_proper_part> some 
            (obo:OBI_0000576
             and (obo:BFO_0000053 some obo:DRON_00000028)
             and (obo:BFO_0000071 some obo:DRON_00018679))
```

Run through **https://github.com/turbomam/owl2sparql4turbo/blob/master/src/main/scala/ROTS.scala**...

```
import java.io.File
import scala.compat.java8.StreamConverters.RichStream
import org.aksw.owl2sparql.OWLClassExpressionToSPARQLSubClassQueryConverter
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.search.EntitySearcher

object ROTS {

  // SPARQL searches for Rosuvastatin Oral Tablet classes

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager()
    var ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File("rots.owl"))

    // use a factory to convert stings to IRI objects
    var factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory()
    var termIRI = IRI.create("http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00081385")
    var someClass = factory.getOWLClass(termIRI)

    var classSupers = EntitySearcher.getSuperClasses(someClass, ontology).toScala[Stream]

    var oneSuper = classSupers(0)

    var scConverter = new OWLClassExpressionToSPARQLSubClassQueryConverter()
    var targetVar = "?x"

    var queryStr = scConverter.convert(oneSuper, targetVar)

    println(queryStr)

  }
}
```

generates the output:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?x WHERE {  ?x rdf:type owl:Class ;
     rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                       owl:onProperty <http://www.obofoundry.org/ro/ro.owl#has_proper_part> ;
                       owl:someValuesFrom [ owl:intersectionOf ( <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OBI_0000576>
                                                                 [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                                   owl:onProperty <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000053> ;
                                                                   owl:someValuesFrom <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00000029>
                                                                 ]
                                                                 [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                                   owl:onProperty <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000071> ;
                                                                   owl:someValuesFrom <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_30618>
                                                                 ]
                                                               ) ;
                                            rdf:type owl:Class
                                          ]
                     ] .
}
```